# Elasticsearch activation trouble

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am currently trying to setup Elasticsearch for a project that i have with Django. I have installed Elasticsearch 7.4.1.

But when I try to start **Elasticsearch** using the command

```
sudo -i service elasticsearch start
```

I get the error below :

```
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And when I try to run the command

```
lasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; v>
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2021-07-11 17:35:09 -03; 1min 2s>
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
    Process: 6654 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p >
   Main PID: 6654 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

jul 11 17:34:56 usuario-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch.>
jul 11 17:35:09 usuario-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: >
jul 11 17:35:09 usuario-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: >
jul 11 17:35:10 usuario-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Failed to start Elastic>
```

I have removed/purged Elasticsearch from my machine and re-installed several times, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

I have tried to modify the default network.host and host.port settings in /etc/default/elasticsearch to network.host: 0.0.0.0 and http.port: 9200 to fix the issue, but no luck yet.

I need some assistance. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: why your log is incomplete? you didnt need to reinstall elasticsearch. run journalctl -u elasticsearch.service > elastic.log and attach elastic.log here

Comment: That gives me : ``` -- Logs begin at Fri 2021-05-21 16:20:25 -03, end at Sat 2021-07-17 20:41:16 -03. --
jul 11 17:34:56 usuario-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
jul 11 17:35:09 usuario-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
jul 11 17:35:09 usuario-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
jul 11 17:35:10 usuario-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
 ``` but indeed i have no more solutions

Comment: Try starting ES manually. Makes it easier to see messages. Check the Es logs.

Comment: If you started Elasticsearch with systemd, then the Elasticsearch logs should be in /var/log/elasticsearch/.